# Close, they were. Now, so far

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> One happy pair, they just wed,
>   And their love, they will spread.
>   Saw them once, they pass by;
>   With joyance, cheered by nation,
>   A single word, thought I,
>   Can itself, sum the situation.
>
> Years have passed, love is slain,
>   Now they go, different ways.
>   They divorced, but again,
>   A single word, fits the case.
>   The second word, like the first,
>   Two core letters, just reversed.

Comment: Are both the words nouns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think two words for the two verses may be (but this reply may be missing clues)

> UNITED and UNTIED

One happy pair, they just wed,
And their love, they will spread.

> The first verse describing united - they wed is united

Saw them once, they pass by;
With joyance, cheered by nation,

> May be the United Nations

A single word, thought I, Can itself, sum the situation.

> The first word being united

Years have passed, love is slain,
Now they go, different ways.

> Untied so may go different ways

They divorced, but again,
A single word, fits the case.

> Untied for divorced

The second word, like the first,
Two core letters, just reversed.

> Un**it**ed and Un**ti**ed have the two core (middle) letters reversed